# Consulta de dados na Web no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, planilha

trabalho em uma empresa e preciso monitorar a vida útil de toners das impressoras diariamente...

Para isso criei uma planilha de monitoramento, só que queria um sistema prático, tipo assim:

Quando eu inserir o endereço da web em uma célula da planilha, automaticamente do lado aparecer a página da web...
Isso é para evitar ir no navegador, olhar, e depois inserir a porcentagem.
 Mas eu queria tipo um frame dentro da planilha.Por exemplo: Eu coloco o endereço "google.com" na célula A7, aí automaticamente do lado aparecia a exibição da página. É possível

Comment: Siga [este Tutorial em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21859804/7690982), use o tradutor caso necessário.

Comment: Caso seu Excel seja maior do que o 2013, [ler isto](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793374/cannot-insert-certain-scriptable-activex-controls-into-office-2013-doc), em que a Microsoft desabilitou esta opção por motivos de segurança. Mas se qainda quiser se arriscar, realize os passos do link.

Comment: Desse jeito eu já tentei porém não aparece a barra para inserir uma URL.
Eu queria inserir uma URL em alguma barra ou célula e automaticamente aparecer a visualização da página da WEB ao lado.
É possível?

Comment: Sim, ao invés de `Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://www.google.com"`, você utiliza uma variável no lugar de google.com e insere os valores como Textbox no userform e usa algum botão para iniciar.

Comment: Não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isto. 
Me dá um exemplo por gentileza?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1) Entrar no VBA

1. Habilite o [modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Abra o VBA ou aperte <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>

### 2) Adicionar Userform

Na janela de Projetos, clique com o botão direito e Insira um `Userform`

[image: ![Inserir Userform]

### 3) Inserir Web Browser

Dentro do Userform, inserir o Browser.

1. Clique em `Ferramentas` e depois `Controles adicionais...`
   [image: Controles adicionais...]
2. Ou com o botão direito na Caixa de Ferramentas
   [image: Controles adicionais...]
3. Dentro de `Controles Adicionais...`, habilitar `Microsoft Web Browser`. Com isso a foto de um planeta será inserida na Caixa de Ferramentas
   [image: Microsoft Web Browser]
4. Inserir Web Browser dentro do Userform, clicando no planeta.
   [image: Inserir Web Browser]

### 4)Inserir TextBox

Clique no botão da caixa de ferramentas da imagem e insira a TextBox

[image: TextBox]

### 5)Inserir Botão

Clique no botão da imagem e insira um botão de comando.

[image: Botão]

### 6)Código

1. Clique para Exibir o código do Userform

[image: Exibir código]

2. Inserir o código.

   ```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim web_link As String

       web_link = TextBox1
       Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate web_link
   End Sub
   ```

### 7)Resultado

[image: Resultado]

O Userform pode ser melhorado, como por exemplo, abrindo uma janela que é redimensionado para a tela inteira. E para chamar o Userform, basta adicionar algum botão, para isto há vários tutoriais.

> Obs.: Caso o Web Browser não funcione, leia [este link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793374/cannot-insert-certain-scriptable-activex-controls-into-office-2013-doc) para habilitá-lo. Lembre-se que o mesmo foi desabilitado do Excel 2013 ou maior, para melhorar a segurança.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado.